# How to sort Domain-Objects with attribute with type JodaTime / DateTime in grails 1.3.7?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, jodatime, grails-controller

I'm working on a small event calendar and i want to sort the events by start time!

I'm using JodaTime Plugin in grails for the startTime attribute. ( http://www.grails.org/JodaTime+Plugin )

So, how can i sort with this datatype? This does not work:

```
def sortedEvents = events.asList().sort({ a, b -> a.startTime <=> b.startTime } as Comparator)
```

I hope you can help me!

Thanks,
whitenexx

/EDIT/
This is the code where i'm getting the events:

```
    def getEventsNext(Location location) {
        def events = location.events.findAll { it.endTime >= new DateTime() }
    def sortedEvents = events.sort{it.startTime}
    System.out.println(sortedEvents); //test
    return sortedEvents
}
```

In /event/list action everything works fine with g:sortableColumn (sorting by startTime):
[image: /event/list]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def sortedEvents = events.asList().sort{it.startTime}
```

To reverse the sorting order, use:

```
def sortedEvents = events.asList().sort{-it.startTime}
```

FYI, Groovy adds this `sort()` method to `Collection` so you can  remove `asList()` from the code above if `events` is already a `Collection`.

Comment: This doesn't work too. I think my mistake is elsewhere. I'm updating my first post/question. Please look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `compareTo` method in your domain classes.

For example,

```
int compareTo(obj) {
    startTime.compareTo(obj.startTime)
}
```

### Edit

Sort your events like so:

```
def sortedEvents = events.sort{e1,e2-> e1.startTime.compareTo(2.startTime)}
```

Or as suggested by @Don, the groovier equivalent

```
def sortedEvents = events.sort{e1,e2-> e1.startTime <=> e2.startTime}
```

Comment: I think `startTime <=> obj.startTime` is a slightly Groovier equivalent

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Maybe my getEventsNext() method is incorrect? I've edited my first post/question, please look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def events = location.events.findAll { it.endTime.isAfterNow() }
def sortedEvents = events.sort{it.startTime.toDate()}
```

[JavaDoc for isAfterNow()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfterNow%28%29)